# How to marshall an array of structs?

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const int SystemPowerInformation = 11;
        const uint STATUS_SUCCESS = 0;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION
        {
            public uint  Number;
            public uint MaxMhz;
            public uint CurrentMhz;
            public uint MhzLimit;
            public uint MaxIdleState;
            public uint CurrentIdleState;
        }

        [DllImport("powrprof.dll")]
        static extern uint CallNtPowerInformation(
            int InformationLevel,
            IntPtr lpInputBuffer,
            int nInputBufferSize,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
            out byte[]  lpOutputBuffer,
            int nOutputBufferSize
        );

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION))];
            uint retval = CallNtPowerInformation(
                SystemPowerInformation,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                0,
                out  buffer,
                4 * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION))
            );

            if (retval == STATUS_SUCCESS)
                Console.WriteLine(buffer);
       }
    }
}
```

I am trying to get some data out of `CallNtPowerInformation`. I tried to create a struct and call `CallNtPowerInformation` and marshal the data from it, but that didn't work. So I am trying to see if I can get the data into a byte array, but I get the following:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I believe I am allocating the memory to the buffer.

I am not sure why. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Using *out* for the lpOutputBuffer argument is not correct, remove it.  Using byte[] doesn't help either, declare an overload of the method that uses PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION[] as the argument type.

Comment: Don't use "out" parameter modifier. CallNtPowerInformation just fills in the memory buffer, it doesn't allocate the buffer.

Comment: I see the mistake I made I am basically doing int**. when I need int*

Comment: When I use PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION[] I am getting all zeros whereas if I use the a byte array I am getting some data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constant named `SystemPowerInformation` with value `11` has the wrong name. It should be named `ProcessorInformation`.

You should declare the p/invoke like this:

```
[DllImport("powrprof.dll")]
static extern uint CallNtPowerInformation(
    int InformationLevel,
    IntPtr lpInputBuffer,
    int nInputBufferSize,
    [Out] PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION[] processorPowerInformation,
    int nOutputBufferSize
);
```

In order to call the function you need to allocate a suitably sized array of `PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION` structs. Like this:

```
PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION[] powerInfo = 
    new PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION[procCount];
```

The documentation for `CallNtPowerInformation` tells you to use `GetSystemInfo` to work out how many processors you have. You can use `Environment.ProcessorCount`.

Then you call the function like this:

```
uint retval = CallNtPowerInformation(
    ProcessorInformation,
    IntPtr.Zero,
    0,
    powerInfo,
    powerInfo.Length*Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION))
);
```

Here's a complete program:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const int ProcessorInformation = 11;
        const uint STATUS_SUCCESS = 0;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION
        {
            public uint Number;
            public uint MaxMhz;
            public uint CurrentMhz;
            public uint MhzLimit;
            public uint MaxIdleState;
            public uint CurrentIdleState;
        }

        [DllImport("powrprof.dll")]
        static extern uint CallNtPowerInformation(
            int InformationLevel,
            IntPtr lpInputBuffer,
            int nInputBufferSize,
            [Out] PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION[] lpOutputBuffer,
            int nOutputBufferSize
        );

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int procCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;
            PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION[] procInfo =
                new PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION[procCount]; 
            uint retval = CallNtPowerInformation(
                ProcessorInformation,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                0,
                procInfo,
                procInfo.Length * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION))
            );
            if (retval == STATUS_SUCCESS)
            {
                foreach (var item in procInfo)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.CurrentMhz);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually copied example from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20407094/c-sharp-how-to-use-callntpowerinformation-with-interop-to-get-system-power-infor I didn't rename everything

Comment: Yes, I thought the code in the question was written by me. I recognise the very particular layout, and the name `retval`! Anyway, the code in this answer works.

Comment: It look like the [Out] was what I was missing. Once I put that in my code the Marshalling process worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Change the parameter type of your umnanaged call to IntPtr:

```
[DllImport("powrprof.dll")]
    static extern uint CallNtPowerInformation(
        int InformationLevel,
        IntPtr lpInputBuffer,
        int nInputBufferSize,
        IntPtr lpOutputBuffer,
        int nOutputBufferSize
    );
```

And use this before calling it:

```
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(obj, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr ptr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
```

Then call it passing that IntPtr as the parameter.

Don't forget to release after use!